# The last "if" statement is not working when I run the program

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, break

Every time I run the program, the last "if" statement is not working, it means if I type "no", the loop won't break. Can someone please help me here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int age, i;
  char ans;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("\n enter your age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age > 18) {
      printf("your age is %d, you are allowed to enter", age);
    } else if (age == 18) {
      printf("I don't know what to do with you");
    } else {
      printf("your age is %d, you are not allowed to go in", age);
    }

    printf("\n continue?");
    scanf(" %c", &ans);

    if (ans == 'no') {  // <-- here
      break;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` scans only a character, use `if (ans == 'n') { ...` or `char ans[4]; scanf(" %s", ans); if (strcmp(ans, "no") == 0){ ...`

Comment: Activate warning, you will get the issue pointed out.

Comment: ans == 'no' won't work; as David says, use strcmp.

Comment: It was already mentioned that string comparisons don't work this way. Besides that, `'no'` is no string. It is an multy character literal which is an integer with implementation defined value. Use `"no"` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `if (ans == 'n')`. If you want to use the word `"no"`, you have to change the type of variable `ans` to char array and use `strcmp()` method to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

In c programming single quotes (i.e. 'c') are used for characters and double quotes (i.e. "c") are used for strings. In double quotes last character is NULL.

Note: We cannot keep two characters in single quote like 'no'.

In your case first thing, declare ans as character array(i.e. string).

```
char ans[SIZE_AS_PER_REQUIREMENT];
```

[To take input](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/) in this,

```
scanf("%s",ans);
```

For a better user experience before taking input give a proper message to user.

```
printf("\n Do you want to continue(yes/no)?");
```

Now to compare user's answer with program's condition, We have C-Language string library (i.e. [string.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/string.h)), include this before using any C-language inbuilt String function.

```
#include <string.h>
```

and use any of string function [strcmp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strcmp-in-c-cpp/) or [stricmp](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rtref/stricmp.htm) as per requirement. Here I am going to use *stricmp* because it is possible that user may enter "no"/"No"/"NO". stricmp ignore the case.

```
stricmp(string1,string2)
```

It returns

- Negative Number if string1 is less than string2
- Zero if string1 equivalent to string2
- Positive Number if string1 is greater than string2

So, for our case we check for Zero.

See the below program, I just added these in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
  int age, i;
  char ans[5];//declare ans as character array

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("\n enter your age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (age > 18) {
      printf("your age is %d, you are allowed to enter", age);
    } else if (age == 18) {
      printf("I don't know what to do with you");
    } else {
      printf("your age is %d, you are not allowed to go in", age);
    }

    printf("\n Do you want to continue(yes/no)?");
    scanf("%s",ans);//take input as string in ans, its character array

    if (stricmp(ans,"no") == 0) {  // 0 means both are equal
      break;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You used `%c` which is for characters.
Instead, use `%s`.